# Undocumented error in dcast.data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, resampling

(This was posted previously at the [data-table-help mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/strange-undocumented-data-table-error-td4691467.html), but it's been a few weeks without comment, and I did a little more to try to debug it.)

I ran into a strange error that an internet search only turns up in the commit log of `data.table`:

```
# Error in dcast.data.table(test.table, as.formula(paste(class.col, "+",  : 
#   retFirst must be integer vector the same length as nrow(i)
```

This came up on running a previously tested working dcast.data.table expression, on a data.table I have subsetted by randomly resampling `Trial` with replacement. The offending section is this:

```
dcast.data.table(test.table, 
                 Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel,
                 value.var = "Voltage",
                 fun.aggregate=identity)
```

It seems to be choking on near-duplicate rows in the input table (i.e., the error is the same with or without the `id` column present in the table):

```
test.table <- structure(list(Trial = c(1169L, 1169L), Sample = c(155L, 155L
), Class = c(1L, 1L), Subject = structure(c(13L, 13L), .Label = c("s01", 
"s02", "s03", "s04", "s05", "s06", "s07", "s08", "s09", "s10", 
"s11", "s12", "s13"), class = "factor"), Channel = c(1L, 1L), 
    Voltage = structure(c(-0.992322316444497, -0.992322316444497
    ), "`scaled:center`" = -6.23438399446429e-16, "`scaled:scale`" = 1), 
    Time = c(201.149466192171, 201.149466192171), Baseline = c(0.688151312347969, 
    0.688151312347969), id = 1:2), .Names = c("Trial", "Sample", 
"Class", "Subject", "Channel", "Voltage", "Time", "Baseline", 
"id"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), sorted = "id")    

test.table
#    Trial Sample Class Subject Channel    Voltage     Time  Baseline id
# 1:  1169    155     1     s13       1 -0.9923223 201.1495 0.6881513  1
# 2:  1169    155     1     s13       1 -0.9923223 201.1495 0.6881513  2
dcast.data.table(test.table, 
                  Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel,
                  value.var = "Voltage",
                  fun.aggregate=identity)
# Error in dcast.data.table(test.table, Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel,  : 
#   retFirst must be integer vector the same length as nrow(i)
```

Changing a single column in the `dcast` formula gets close to the output I am looking for:

```
test.table[2,Trial:=1170]
dcast.data.table(test.table, 
                  Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel,
                  value.var = "Voltage",
                  fun.aggregate=identity)
#    Class     Time Trial          1
# 1:     1 201.1495  1169 -0.9923223
# 2:     1 201.1495  1170 -0.9923223
```

What's bothering data.table? I tried changing keys and messing with the order of the formula terms just to see, because I don't understand the error, but that didn't work.

If I replace the function call with regular `dcast` from `reshape2`, I get a seemingly unrelated error:

```
# Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be length 0, but FUN(X[[29]]) result is length 1
```

At this point in my code I don't care if the `Trial` values are correct, so I could work around this by replacing it in the formula with `id`, but I'm interested in a more general or robust solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if your example were [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You have not included sample data such that we can run your code exactly and encounter the same error.

Comment: I agree, and I mentioned in the question that I would like to know what the error means so that I have a clue on how to reproduce it in a concise way, instead of populating the question with a ton of (possibly irrelevant) code.

Comment: I wouldn't say the errors are un related, both appear to suggest there is a case where a return value is not the length it "should" be. A reproducible example will be required. Try and find a minimal subset of the data on which the error occurs, and then use gist.github or similar to host the data.

Comment: I narrowed it down to `dcast` of identical rows and managed to get a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update: Fixed in [commit 1253](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/b142804872df7f22fa3af7656e6a153a09b7efa2) of v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> - `dcast.data.table` provides better error message when `fun.aggregate` is specified but it returns length != 1. Closes git [#693](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/693). Thanks to Trevor Alexander for reporting [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152733/undocumented-error-in-dcast-data-table).

---

I agree that the error message should be more helpful in understanding the issue and it usually is in data.table. This is just a case I hadn't foreseen.

If you could please file the issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/datatable) as a bug, I'll fix it when I've some time.

---

Your problem, however, seems quite trivial RTFM to me. From `?dcast.data.table`:

> `fun.aggregate` - Should the data be aggregated before casting? If the formula doesn't identify single observation for each cell, then aggregation defaults to length with a message.
>
> In the **DETAILS** section: *"... fun.aggregate will have to be used. The aggregating function should take a vector as input and return a single value (or a list of length one) as output." ...*

In your example, your formula's LHS results in two identical rows, which means `fun.aggregate` has to be used - which'll default to `length` if you dint use one (like `reshape2:::dcast` does). And you've used `identity`, which'll just return the values back. So it returns both the values for `Voltage`, which the function doesn't like.

The error message should be something like:

> Error: `fun.aggregate` should return, for each unique group (from formula's `LHS`), a length 1 vector, but returns `length=2` for a group.

Or something of that sort. Feel free to suggest better / clearer error messages.

---

PS: I don't understand what you mean by *near-duplicate*.

```
identical(test.table[1, list(Class, Time, Trial)], 
          test.table[2, list(Class, Time, Trial)])
# [1] TRUE
```

If you use `id` column on the LHS, then you should be able to get the desired result, as you can now uniquely identify the rows...

```
dcast.data.table(test.table, 
             Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel + id,
             value.var = "Voltage",
             fun.aggregate=identity)

#    Class     Time Trial        1_1        1_2
# 1:     1 201.1495  1169 -0.9923223 -0.9923223
```

The function only considers the columns given in the formula LHS to find out if there are/aren't unique rows, not if your actual input data has unique rows (if that was the confusion).

---

To answer OP's 2nd comment:

The only way currently to get a result (without error) is if your function returns a list:

```
dcast.data.table(test.table, 
             Class + Time + Trial ~ Channel,
             value.var = "Voltage",
             fun.aggregate=list)
#    Class     Time Trial                     1
# 1:     1 201.1495  1169 -0.9923223,-0.9923223
```

Then you can just check if the columns are all of length 1 and if so, unlist.

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more clear; sorry about that. I definitely don't have a problem with the *behavior* of `dcast.data.table`, and this error wasn't really irritating, just confusing. What I meant by near-duplicate was that the *input* table does not contain duplicates (when given unique ids as I did in the `dput`), but the formula I gave it causes non-unique rows to be generated. These subtleties were lost on me coming back to the insides of a function I wrote and tested two months ago and promptly forgot how it worked :) I think your proposed error message is perfect for this.

Comment: I filed the issue at github. I agree with your workaround too for the `id` column--it's what I went with today (see end of the question), but it's sort of unsatisfying because it has to be worked in based on the structure of the input; it would be nice if there was some way to 'coerce uniqueness' in a way that would not affect the structure of the output so much.